# How to do user authentication

Tags: php, authentication

Is there any ways to do user authentication besides session?

And is there anyway to do user authentication checking besides

```
if($_USER != null){
   ...
}
```

Comment: You can use cookies. Just be aware that a user can tamper with the cookie data since it's stored in THEIR browser.

Sessions are relatively safer compared to cookies as it is less likely someone will hack your server vs a user modifying their cookies.

Remember to always sanitize your inputs.

Comment: Once your web app hits a certain scale, you will likely use a webscaler and then sessions are not stored on the same machine. You can store your sessions in a database but then your database will be hit more often but it works with the netscaler.

Read more about cookies and sessions here: http://www.sitepoint.com/baking-cookies-in-php/

Answer (score 0):

You could do user authentication using basic or digest http authentication.
Check http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php for a basic example.

You could also setup cookie based (not recommended!), or create a mysql based
alternative to sessions.

Answer (score 0):

If it's just for a prompt access box, you can use something like htpassword.

But if it's an "in-page" solution, I would create a "loggedIn" function that either returns true or false, and if it's necessary check the different levels:

```
function loggedIn(){
  if(isset($_SESSION['user']){
    //check the user level/permissions
  } else{
    //return false OR redirect
  }
}
```

This makes it possible to send an access level in as a parameter, if you have admin/moderator pages.

Answer (score 0):

For those interested in using cookie-based authentication, I built an open source PHP user auth library that has a heavy emphasis on security and ease of use. It handles everything from registering new users to sending password recovery and account activation emails. User info is stored on the client in an encrypted cookie which is used for authentication and retrieving user data such as userID, user email, etc.

https://github.com/ejfrancis/alpine-auth